# Can I get a lastUpdated column on my tables using triggers?

Tags: cassandra

I want to add a `lastUpdated` column on my cassandra tables, and have this column autopopulated by cassandra whenever a row is updated.

Does cassandra have triggers that could do this?

The goal is not to have to update code base, just a db migration to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra stores the write time for each column/row/partition. In fact, this is what the coordinators use to determine the latest version of the data and returns it to the clients.

Depending on what you're after, you can use this metadata for your purposes without having to store it separately. There is a built-in function `WRITETIME()` that returns the timestamp in microseconds for when the data was written ([details here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlSelect.html#cqlSelect__retrieving-the-datetime-a-write-occurred)).

On the subject of database triggers, they exist in Cassandra but there hasn't been much work done for this functionality for 5 (maybe 7) years so I personally wouldn't recommend their use. I think triggers were always considered experimental and never moved on. In fact, they were deprecated in DataStax Enterprise around 5 years ago. Cheers!

Comment: WRITETIME is interesting, the tricky part is that it is at the column level...I need it at the row level otherwise I need to call it for each column

Comment: @Blankman The same applies for the row. If you know for sure that your app only updates the whole row and not individual columns, you can just get the `WRITETIME()` of a single column. Cheers!